# Are Cronbach's alpha of the subscale the same as in correlated-factor model and bifactor model?

Tags: reliability, cronbachs-alpha

I have an instrument that holds a correlated-factor model and a bifactor model (one general model and four orthogonal factors). I need to report the reliability of each subscale. I've computed Omega (model level and factor level) for the bifactor model, but I don't know how to compute Cronbach's alpha for subscales in the bifactor model or it is the same as the value in the correlated-factor model? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No.

In a bifactor model, each specific factor is made to be orthogonal to the general factor, essentially by subtracting general factor scores from each of the specific factors. As a result, specific factors in the bifactor model don't measure the same thing as the corresponding specific factors in the correlated factors model, and, because you've removed any variance that's due to the general factor, **specific factor scores from the bifactor model will have much lower reliability than the corresponding specific factors in the correlated factors model**.

All that said, it's easy to calculate omega for bifactor models, e.g. (using R):

> Big caveat: The `semTools::reliability()` function assumes you've reverse-coded the negative items, which I haven't done here, so the actual values are wrong.

```r
library(lavaan)
library(psych) # For the bfi dataset
library(semTools) # For semTools::reliabilty
code = '
  A =~ A1 + A2 + A3 + A4 + A5
  O =~ O1 + O2 + O3 + O4 + O5
  C =~ C1 + C2 + C3 + C4 + C5
  g =~ A1 + A2 + A3 + A4 + A5 +
       O1 + O2 + O3 + O4 + O5 +
       C1 + C2 + C3 + C4 + C5
'
model = cfa(code, data = bfi, std.lv = T)
summary(model)
reliability(model)
```

### Update

You calculate omega for the correlated factors model in exactly the same way:

```r
code_not_bifactor = '
  A =~ A1 + A2 + A3 + A4 + A5
  O =~ O1 + O2 + O3 + O4 + O5
  C =~ C1 + C2 + C3 + C4 + C5
'
model2 = cfa(code_not_bifactor, data = bfi, std.lv = T)
reliability(model2)
#                A           O           C
# alpha  0.4388452 -0.16514916 -0.30499264
# omega  0.5749869  0.02994570  0.01836783
# omega2 0.5749869  0.02994570  0.01836783
# omega3 0.5739865  0.02620328  0.01476073
# avevar 0.3461883  0.25023511  0.36586700
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have computed omega for the bifactor model, but I don't know how to compute omega for the correlated-factor model. Is it make sense to report Cronbach's alpha for the correlated-factor model and omega for the bifactor model?

Comment: See the edited response.